# HQL many to many query in the same class

Tags: java, many-to-many, hql

I have a database with two tables, Account and Favorites. Favorites is a many-to-many table. It holds:

```
listowner (foreign key referencing the Account primary key)
favorite (also a foreign key referencing the Account primary key)
```

Favorites does not have its own class in my program. I only have Account.java, which holds two sets.

```
private Set<Account> favorites;
private Set<Account> listOwner;
//the getters and setters for these sets
```

The relevant mapping file:

```
<set name="favorites" table="favorites" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="listowner" />
        <many-to-many column="favorite"  class="Models.Account" />
 </set>

<set name="listOwner" table="favorites" cascade="all">
        <key column="favorite" />
        <many-to-many column="listowner" class="Models.Account" />
</set>
```

Now, saving to the database works fine. I can save a favorite account with a listowner and see him appear when directly accessing the database. But I can't get this information out of the database again. I want a list of all favorites of an account. In SQL, this would be:

```
SELECT favorite 
FROM favorites 
WHERE listowner = "Bob"
```

My current attempt:

```
 public static List<Account> getFavorites(Account account)
{
    List<Account> list = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        list = session.createQuery("from Account a where a.listOwner.accountName = :name").setParameter("name", account.getAccountName()).list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (tx != null)
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        System.out.println("getFavorites failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

According to the debugger, it's failing on

```
 list = session.createQuery("from Account a where a.listOwner.accountName = :name").setParameter("name", account.getAccountName()).list();
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any exceptions.

Comment: If its not throwing any exceptions, how do you say that its failing?!

Comment: It's not throwing any exception because the OP catches all possible exceptions instead of simply letting them propagate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. `a.listOwner` is of type `Set<Account>`. And a `Set<Account>` doesn't have any `accountName` property. To be able to add restrictions on an element of `a.listOwner`, you need an explicit join:

```
select a from Account a 
inner join a.listOwner owner
where owner.accountName = :name
```

That said, your whole method should simply be replaced by

```
return account.getFavorites();
```

Comment: First one works, but your second one is even better. Sometimes I overthink things. Thanks a bunch!